# Detecting change in value in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a scenario where I need to render a div on the screen based on a boolean flag. The value of the flag is received from a service.

```
  <div *ngIf="isEnabled()" class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <menu-bar></menu-bar>
        </div>
```

By the time the service returns a boolean value, the isEnabled function returns null. Is there any way to render this div after the subscription of service is successful?

Below is the Component I am using:

```
export class MainAppComponent implements OnInit{

    static enabled : boolean = true;
    license : string;
    errorMessage : string;
    fatalError : boolean;
    mode = 'Observable';

    constructor(private licenseService : LicenceService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.licenseService.getLicenseInfo()
            .subscribe(info => {
                                if(info) {
                                    SharedService.isLicesePresent = true;
                                } else {
                                    SharedService.isLicesePresent = false;
                                }
                            },
                       error => {
                           this.fatalError = true;
                               this.errorMessage = <any>error;
                               swal({
                                   title: ' Error',
                                   type: 'warning',
                                   text: 'Network Error. Please contact customer support',
                               })

                            });
    }

    isEnabled() : boolean {
        return SharedService.isLicesePresent;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code written in `isEnabled()` function

Comment: What is `SharedService`. There should probably be a `this.` in front of it.

Comment: Its kind of a utility class with a static variable isLicesePresent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the observable to the property `isEnabled` and use the async pipe

```
this.isEnabled = someService.getStatus();
```

```
    <div *ngIf="isEnabled | async" class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <menu-bar></menu-bar>
    </div>
```